# curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized

Tags: nginx, centos7, curl

I have the following error when I try to curl a server :

```
curl -u User:Pass 'https://mydomain/remote.php/dav/files/User/Folder' -X PROPFIND --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
```

Error is as fallowing :

> curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized. More details
> here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
> "bundle"  of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
> default  bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
> using the --cacert option. If this HTTPS server uses a certificate
> signed by a CA represented in  the bundle, the certificate
> verification probably failed due to a  problem with the certificate
> (it might be expired, or the name might  not match the domain name in
> the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the
> certificate, use  the -k (or --insecure) option.

And when I do `curl -v google.com` it's working fine :

> - About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
> - Trying 2a00:1450:4007:815::200e...
> - Connected to google.com (2a00:1450:4007:815::200e) port 80 (#0)
>   GET / HTTP/1.1
>   User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
>   Host: google.com
>   Accept: */*
>   < HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently < Location: http://www.google.com/ < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 < Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2020
>   07:41:54 GMT < Expires: Sat, 01 Aug 2020 07:41:54 GMT < Cache-Control:
>   public, max-age=2592000 < Server: gws < Content-Length: 219 <
>   X-XSS-Protection: 0 < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN <
>
> 301 Moved
>
> ## 301 Moved
>
> The document
> has moved [here](http://www.google.com/). 
> * Connection #0 to host google.com left intact

I tried :

- `yum reinstall ca-certificates`

---

- `curl --remote-name --time-cond cacert.pem https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem`
- `mv cacert.pem  /etc/ssl/certs/`
- Adding `curl.cainfo="/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"` to php.ini
- Restarting nginx

---

- `yum install ca-certificates`
- `update-ca-trust force-enable`
- Restart nginx
- `cp /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`
- `mv /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/cacert.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/cert.pem`
- Restart nginx

None of them worked

Comment: Where did you get the server certificate?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I get the certificate from https://curl.haxx.se

Comment: Huh? They do not issue SSL certificates!

Comment: Server certificate got from letsencrypt